# I'm attempting to enable postfix filtering in fail2ban and systemd won't let it start

Tags: postfix, fail2ban

systemctl status fail2ban.service

```
    * fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled;             vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-10     05:36:32 EDT; 7s ago
         Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 3157 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3318 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 3135 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 10 05:36:31 lynch-family systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
May 10 05:36:31 lynch-family systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 10 05:36:31 lynch-family systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 10 05:36:32 lynch-family systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 10 05:36:32 lynch-family systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
May 10 05:36:32 lynch-family systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 10 05:36:32 lynch-family systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
```

and

journalctl -xe

```
-- Unit fail2ban.service has finished shutting down.
May 10 05:35:04 lynch-family systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 10 05:35:04 lynch-family systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
-- Subject: Unit fail2ban.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit fail2ban.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

(Removed a bunch of mail.log lines)

This is running service fail2ban start or restart.  If I disable postfix it works: 
Relevant part of jail.local:

```
[postfix]
enabled = true

port     = smtp,465,submission
logpath  = %(postfix_log)s
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with new version of Fail2Ban Monitor on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

With the new update they made a bit more structure on config.

But when you start a service ***fail2ban*** then you get detailed output to *syslog* something like this

```
Nov  2 02:05:16 xost fail2ban-client[3171]: ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/mail.warn
Nov  2 02:05:16 xost fail2ban-client[3171]: ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for postfix jail
```

or like this

```
Nov  2 02:28:35 xost fail2ban-client[9365]: ERROR  Failed during configuration: Bad value substitution: option 'logpath' in section 'sshd' contains an interpolation key 'syslog_authpriv' which is not a valid option name. Raw value: '%(sshd_log)s'
Nov  2 02:28:35 xost systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Nov  2 02:28:35 xost systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
```

Just make sure you filled in all vars.

In jail.conf put the proper vars file:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = paths-common.conf
```

And in this file check that all logs you going to monitor are indicated

```
# There is no sensible generic defaults for syslog log targets, thus
# leaving them empty here so that no errors while parsing/interpolating configs
syslog_daemon =
syslog_ftp = /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
syslog_local0 =
syslog_mail_warn = /var/log/mail.log
syslog_user =
```

In my example, since I expect to monitor ***postfix*** and ***proftpd*** I had to put the paths of their logs

Answer (score 1):

> I found [the] problem.  I set the logpath to `/var/log/mail.log` and it
>   works OK now.  I searched for a variable (?) named `postfix_log` but it
>   isn't defined anywhere I could see.

-- noted as solved by OP in the question.